# Combining several searches in Elastic to one, in order to reduce HTTP calls (with Java high level REST client)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

(The following example is derived from a true business logic, that was altered in order to be published here).

In our Pub application, we have an Elastic Search that holds records that look like that:

- The name of the customer,
- what he drank
- and how much

A fictional sample:

```
{
   "name": "Alice",
   "drink": "Beer",
   "amount": "2"
}
{
  "name": "Alice",
  "drink": "Coffee",
   "amount": "1"
}
{
  "name": "Alice",
  "drink": "Tea",
   "amount": "5"
}
{
 "name": "Bob",
 "drink": "Coffee",
 "amount": "3"
 }
 {
  "name": "Bob",
  "drink": "Daiquiri",
  "amount": "1"
 }
  .....
```

Elastic Search document structure can't be changed, and we must fulfill the task with this structure.

When a guest is asking for a bill, the *Bartender* needs to calculate the bill for the *Alcoholic* drinks of the guest, and the *Barista* needs to calculate the bill for the *non-Alcoholic* drinks of the guest.

So if `Alice` is checking out, the current call of the *Barista*, to Elastic, seems like that:

```
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(....);
    BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", "Alice"));
    queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("drink", "Coffee", "Tea", "Coca Cola"....));
```

We like to make the calls more efficient, so if 10 customers checkout at the same time, our Barista can do only one HTTP request to elastic and get the relevant info **per customer**.

[There is the MultiSearch option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-multi-search.html) , but since all our requests are very similar to each other, we wonder if there is a different way.

Comment: How about using `should` instead of `must` in the `name` part of the query; duplicating the third line for each customer?

Comment: You can combine in bool/must/should queries, if for some reason `_msearch` does not work you (your argument is not very clear why it wouldn't).